# How to set the message ID and time stamp for incoming messages

Tags: android, sms

I am  developing an app that receive sms and I want to know how to 
set message ID and timestamp for incoming messages.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you want to 'set' the message ID and timestamp, do you mean that you want to read them as they are received by the phone? I doubt that you will be able to set these values manually

Comment: actually  i want to keep track  of massages that i have already  read ,so i waz thinking of massage id and time stamp

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you're using an [SmsMessage](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SmsMessage.html) object. This object does not allow you to set any ID or timestamp, but you can retrieve the timestamp with [getTimeStampMillis()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SmsMessage.html#getTimestampMillis%28%29), and there doesn't seem be any ID's in this class. If you want to be able to have and manipulate these values you probably need to write your own Sms-class.

Comment: actualy i want to  keep  track  of massages that have   being already  read thats why i was thinikng of massage id and time stamp

Comment: @MkhululiKhustaricoBuzwa You don't need to set any values for that. Just retrieve. Or am I misunderstanding something? getStatusOnIcc() can give you read/unread status. If you need to have a list of read messages, then maybe create a list of these objects/some id you've made